# how to create a .bin file?

Tags: packaging

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I am stuck at creating a simple .bin file which can print a message "hi" or anything else. My objective is to create a binary file.I have searched but didn't found anything helpful to me. So may I know how can I create a .bin file.

Comment: the extension .bin usually indicates a binary file - more than likely compiled - so if you intend to have a binary file you should pick a programming language, write a program, test it then compile it to get an executable file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extensions are irrelevant, you can name a file `dead.letter` and it can still print "hi".

The following terminal commands will create a file named `hello.bin`, make it executable and print "hello" when executed:

```
cat > hello.bin <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo Hello World
EOF
chmod +x hello.bin
```

Executing `./hello.bin` gives:

```
Hello World
```

This is a shell script, interpreted by the `/bin/sh` program (which is actually the `/bin/dash` program on Ubuntu).

The following writes source code to `hello.c`, the following command creates a binary program from this code:

```
cat > hello.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    puts("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
EOF
gcc hello.c -o hello.bin
```

Executing `./hello.bin` gives you `Hello World` too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will let you know after trying it.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to ubuntu community but had this as a bookmark on my browser.
You can see if this helps.

http://www.ehow.com/how_5962897_create-bin-file-ubuntu.html

Comment: @prohank When you have a link to a page that you believe answers teh question, [it's considered best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If you wish to do that, you can edit your post to add your summary of the information.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because the link is gone now and leads to the wrong answer.